# Determine the value of $k$, if any, that makes k continuous everywhere for this piece wise function.

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

> Let
>   $$
> h(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \sin (kx), & \text{if }x\leq  2, \\
> x+k^2, & \text{if }x>2,
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   where $k$ is a real constant. Determine the value of $k$, if any, that makes k continuous everywhere.

I done my work and here goes.

> > Since $h(x)$ is continuous on $(-\infty,2)$ and on $(2,\infty)$, it suffice to find the value of $k$ such that $h(x)$ is continuous at $x=2$.
> >
> > Suppose $h(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, then $$\lim_{x\to2^-}h(x)=\lim_{x\to2^-}\sin k(x)=\sin(2k)$$
> >     and $$\lim_{x\to2^+}h(x)=\lim_{x\to2^+}x+k^2=2+k^2$$
> >     Therefore, $\lim_{x\to2^+}h(x)=\lim_{x\to2^-}h(x)$ implies $\sin(2k)=2+k^2$

Ok so now I am stuck. Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: $|\sin x|\leq 1$ for any real $x$, so there are no such $k$

Comment: There's no real solutions, but there are two complex, approximately: 0.566±i0.675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work so far is fine.

Hint: $\sin(-)$ is always between -1 and 1.

Comment: Since $1\geq\sin(2k)\geq-1$, then $1\geq2+k^2\geq-1=-1\geq k^2\geq-3$. Therefore, there is no such k.

Answer (score 1):

$-1\leq \sin(2k)\leq 1$ and $2+k^2\geq 2$